# Accessing Dask actor attributes that are not defined explicitly

Tags: python, dask-distributed

[Following the documentation](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/actors.html), it's clear how to access the attributes of a Dask actor if they were defined explicitly at the top of the class definition. However, is it possible to access attributes that were defined implicitly, e.g. during or after init?

Here's a modified example from the docs:

```py
class Counter:
    """ A simple class to manage an incrementing counter """
    n = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
        self.test = 123

    def increment(self):
        self.n += 1
        return self.n
```

As per docs, accessing `counter.n` works well, but `counter.test` will raise `AttributeError`:

> AttributeError: type object 'Counter' has no attribute 'test'

This is more of a curiousity, since in my use case it's easy to move `test` to the top of the class definition. However, I'm curious if there is a hack for accessing attributes that could be created on-the-fly.